# Can I use perl regular expressions in the vim command line?

Tags: vim, regex, perl

I want to use perl regular expressions on the vim command line. For example, to capitalize the words on the current line, you could type:

```
:s/(\w+)/\u$1/g
```

Comment: From **:help perl-patterns** ... **Vim's regexes are most similar to Perl's, in terms of what you can do.  The difference between them is mostly just notation** uhhmm ... that's like saying Chinese is similar to Greek, in terms of what you can communicate. The difference is mostly just notation. **regex is nothing _but_ notation!** The differences are annoying if one notation is less familiar than another. That's why people ask about perl in the first place!

Comment: @felwithe to be fair ... Vim's popularity and prominence predates that of perl ... although that knowledge does not really do much to ease the pain :/

Answer (score 21):

You can filter any line or range of lines through an external command in vim, using !. E.g., you can do:

`:.!perl -pe "s/(\w+)/\u\1/g"`

which will filter the current line through that perl command. ( Here `:` to get into command line mode, and the `.` which follows mean the current line; you can also specify a line range or `%` for the whole file, etc.)

If you want to use vim's built in substitution patterns, the closest you'll come is to use vim's "very magic" option, \v, like so:

`:s/\v(\w+)/\u\1/g`

see `:help pattern` and `:help substitute` for more details. I don't think "very magic" is quite identical to perl's patterns, but is very close. Anyway, you can always use perl itself if you're more comfortable with it, as above.

Comment: also, with very magic, you don't have to memorize that `(` is treated specially while `{` is not: "all ASCII characters except '0'-'9', 'a'-'z', 'A'-'Z' and '_' have a special meaning." thanks!

Answer (score 15):

You can also use:

```
/\v"your regex"
```

instead of:

```
/"your regex"
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for!

Comment: You can also help yourself out by adding `nnoremap / /\v` and `vnoremap / /\v` to your .vimrc so that when you type `/` it just works.

Comment: Ancient answer, but can you explain what `\v` is doing?

Comment: @drevicko Take a look at this documentation: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html

Comment: Ah, ok. `\v` means "very magic": all regex special characters `|(){}.*?^$` (did I miss any?) function as is, and need backslashes to get the literal equivalent, as is the case with perl. You can do most of what perl does with look-arounds etc.., but with different syntax: see http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#perl-patterns

Comment: The sourceforge documentation hasn't been updated since 2010.  Here's a link that's kept up-to-date: https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2Fmagic

Answer (score 12):

No, you can't use Perl regular expressions in that way.  For help in learning the Vim equivalents for Perl regular expression components, see

```
:help perl-patterns
```

However, you can use Perl as an external filter as explained by frabjous.  You can also execute Perl commands within Vim using the Perl interface, if your Vim was compiled with the `+perl` feature.  See

```
:help if_perl.txt
```

Comment: +1, `:help perl-patterns` has resolved the one thing that I previously hated about vim

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution from http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Perl_compatible_regular_expressions

`:perldo s/(\w+)/\u$1/g`

(Verify with `:ver` that `+perl` or `+perl/dyn` is compiled in.)

Answer (score 4):

Use the [eregex.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3282) plugin. It's very useful and I have had no problems with it.